# Search Core Data for all objects with an empty "to-many" relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, many-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In an almost identical situation to [Core Data - Fetch all objects NOT in a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801781/core-data-fetch-all-objects-not-in-a-relationship), only I'm looking for all records of one type that are not in any to-many relationship with another type.

So let's say I've got a set of patients, and a set of lists. Patients can belong to multiple lists, and a list can contain multiple patients.

**How do I find all of the patients that aren't on any list?**
I'm using a Core Data model.

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out. Here's what I did:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"lists.@count == 0"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Then when I ran the fetch request, it only brought up the patients with no list attached.